# Unable to reference a design-time ViewModel in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've done this before, but not for some time and clearly I'm missing something.

In short, I've got a design-time model that inherits from my real view model and sets some properties in the constructor.

I'm importing the namespace in Xaml and IntelliSense is suggesting the desired class name, which leads me to believe my naming is error-free.

Even after a clean/build, I'm getting an error saying that the referenced model doesn't exist.

I can refer to the model from a .cs using `Aurora.UI.ViewModels.SecurityViewModel_DesignTime` without issue.

(In case it matters, this project has a target of x64. This is due to a dependency on an bit-dependent library. It's the only real difference I can point to when comparing to previous implementations).

> The name "SecurityViewModel_DesignTime" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Aurora.UI.ViewModels"

[image: Screenshot showing xaml, project structure and exception]

And the model itself:

```
namespace Aurora.UI.ViewModels {
    public class SecurityViewModel_DesignTime : SecurityViewModel {
        public SecurityViewModel_DesignTime() {
            this.Sensor = new Peripherals.Kinect();
            this.PrimaryFeed = Kinect.Feed.Infrared;
            Feeds = new List<Kinect.Feed> {Kinect.Feed.Infrared};
            this.LookDirections = 
                Peripherals.Kinect.DirectionsRequired.Front | 
                Peripherals.Kinect.DirectionsRequired.Left | 
                Peripherals.Kinect.DirectionsRequired.Right | 
                Peripherals.Kinect.DirectionsRequired.Top;

        }
    }
}
```

(The class it's inheriting from is the 'real' viewModel and is a simple POCO)

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it not building, or is this just the designer having one of its little episodes again?

Comment: Tried to restart Visual Studio?

Comment: @EdPlunkett It completes the compilation with a "success" but the designer then applies one of it's "soft" exceptions. I've actually rebooted for other reasons since seeing this last night.

Comment: This happens sometimes, I've found it gets awfully upset about inheritance. Most of the time a clean & restart of vstudio is what it takes.

Comment: In the past I want to say I've had to manually del the bin/debug folders because for some reason a clean didn't get everything and it behaved afterward. May be worth a shot.

Comment: @Clint Yes! Restarting between a clean and build seems to have done the trick. Care to post as an answer and I'll accept when I can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment, here's an answer:

Do a solution clean, and restart visual studio. Goodness knows why it works. The designer is janky at the best of times.